# why does ruby on rails generates .self what is it for? and how to remove it?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am just puzzled why ruby on rails is generating a lot of .self in its html file. what does it do? is it important? if it's not, how to remove it?

```
<script src="/assets/activestorage.self-0525629bb5bac7ed5f2bfc58a9679d75705e426dafd6957ae9879db97c8e9cbe.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="reload"></script>
<script src="/assets/turbolinks.self-569ee74eaa15c1e2019317ff770b8769b1ec033a0f572a485f64c82ddc8f989e.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="reload"></script>
<script src="/assets/jquery-ui/version.self-c8e3d1203da26ea7efdf83c1eabb3f0ba55cb68e463f5ccf0d77bd15ce6a8e61.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="reload"></script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you set `config.assets.debug = false` in your `development.rb` or in `production.rb`. `self` is no more appended by sprockets. This is basically for, If you want to debug these files individually in your browser otherwise, all these file will be concatenated to `application.js`. Hope this helps.

Comment: I did that earlier but it didn't work, I'm surprised that its working now. Thanks a lot!